# CSS - styling a navbar

Tags: css

Sorry if this is a really simple question, I'm very new to front end design and trying to figure out how to get my nav bar to display properly. All it contains is an image and a search bar but the image is off the page and it seems that adjusting the padding and margin doesn't have any effect. The search bar is fine, it's just the logo that is not displaying properly.

I want the logo to be flushed to the left and the search bar to be centered.

How do I go about styling this?

```
<div class="navbar-top">
  <div class="logo">
    <%= image_tag("logo_01.png", :size => "230x200") %>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="search">
    <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get, class: "product_search" do %>
      <div class="search-field">
        <%= text_field_tag :title, params[:search], placeholder: "Search all products..." %>
      </div>                        
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>           
</div>
```

and my css

```
header.main {

  .navbar-top {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #474747;
    margin-top:-10px;
    display: flex;

    .logo {
      float: left;
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .search {
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 30px;

      input[type=text] {
        width: 500px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      input[type=submit] {
        width: 500px;
        height: 25px;
      }
  }

  .search-field {
    display: inline-block;      
  }
}
```